# numpy - issue with creating a 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have this function that returns a `numpy` array with two vectors that represent `x` and `y` coordinates respectively, and I want to turn them into (x;y) pairs.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

def rotate(coords, angle, center=(0, 0,)):
    rotated = np.array([np.cos(np.radians(angle)) * (coords[:,0] - center[0]) - np.sin(np.radians(angle)) * (coords[:,1] - center[1]) + center[0],
                np.sin(np.radians(angle)) * (coords[:,0] - center[0]) + np.cos(np.radians(angle)) * (coords[:,1] - center[1]) + center[1]])
    return rotated

xy = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[6,7]])
a = rotate(xy,20)
print a
```

This gives me:

```
[[ 0.25565233  1.45099729  2.64634224  3.24401472]
 [ 2.22140538  4.78483091  7.34825644  8.62996921]]
```

However, I actually want this output:

```
[[0.25565233, 2.22140538] 
 [1.45099729, 4.78483091]
 [2.64634224, 7.34825644]
 [3.24401472, 8.62996921]]
```

Comment: I fail to see how the duplicate link addresses the problem in this post.

Comment: You can simplify `rotate` to: `return np.dot([[c, -s], [s, c]], coords - np.array(center)[:, None])`, where `c = np.cos(np.radians(angle))` and `s = np.sin(np.radians(angle))`.  (And then call `a = rotate(xy.T, 20).T`)

Comment: I've also flagged this post for reopening. The duplicate post's objective is to stack 1D numpy arrays into a single 2D array.  This post is concerned with the desired dimensions / shape of an **already created 2D array**.  The answer is to simply transpose the output of the function defined by the OP.  The two are not related in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply take the transpose.  You can use [`numpy.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) or you can use the overloaded operator [`.T`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html):

```
xy = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[6,7]]);
a = rotate(xy,20).T # <--- Modification here
```

Doing this thus gives:

```
>>> print a
[[ 0.25565233  2.22140538]
 [ 1.45099729  4.78483091]
 [ 2.64634224  7.34825644]
 [ 3.24401472  8.62996921]]
```

If you want to avoid transposing the output, you can let the function do that.  Just transpose what is returned inside your `rotate` function:

```
def rotate(coords, angle, center=(0, 0,)):
    rotated = np.array([np.cos(np.radians(angle)) * (coords[:,0] - center[0]) - np.sin(np.radians(angle)) * (coords[:,1] - center[1]) + center[0],
                np.sin(np.radians(angle)) * (coords[:,0] - center[0]) + np.cos(np.radians(angle)) * (coords[:,1] - center[1]) + center[1]])
    return rotated.T #<-- Modification here
```

You can thus do what you did before without thinking about it further:

```
xy = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[6,7]]);
a = rotate(xy,20)
```

... which gives us:

```
>>> print a
[[ 0.25565233  2.22140538]
 [ 1.45099729  4.78483091]
 [ 2.64634224  7.34825644]
 [ 3.24401472  8.62996921]]
```

Comment: yes sorry my mistake I put the .T in the wrong place it works Thank U!!!, i delete my previous commend

Comment: @efirvida - No problem at all :) I've deleted my comment as well.

Comment: @efirvida - BTW, if you require no more help, consider accepting one of our answers.  This tells the StackOverflow community that you no longer need help on this issue. Thanks and good luck!

Comment: I was hoping you spend 10 minutes to vote as I suggested by the site but I amused about something else, sorry

Comment: @efirvida - No problem at all! FWIW, I upvoted your question because it shows effort.  Thanks and good luck!

Comment: @efirvida - De nada. ¡Buena suerte!

Comment: jaja gracias por todo ahi voy con la suerte!

Answer (score 1):

You want to [transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) it -

```
In [3]: n = np.array([[ 0.25565233,  1.45099729,  2.64634224 , 3.24401472],
   ...:  [ 2.22140538 , 4.78483091 , 7.34825644 , 8.62996921]])

In [4]: n
Out[4]:
array([[ 0.25565233,  1.45099729,  2.64634224,  3.24401472],
       [ 2.22140538,  4.78483091,  7.34825644,  8.62996921]])

In [6]: n.T
Out[6]:
array([[ 0.25565233,  2.22140538],
       [ 1.45099729,  4.78483091],
       [ 2.64634224,  7.34825644],
       [ 3.24401472,  8.62996921]])
```

---

In your case -

```
def rotate(coords, angle, center=(0, 0,)):
        rotated = np.array([np.cos(np.radians(angle)) * (coords[:,0] - center[0]) - np.sin(np.radians(angle)) * (coords[:,1] - center[1]) + center[0],
                    np.sin(np.radians(angle)) * (coords[:,0] - center[0]) + np.cos(np.radians(angle)) * (coords[:,1] - center[1]) + center[1]])
        return rotated


xy = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[6,7]])

a = rotate(xy,20)

print a.T
>> [[ 0.25565233  2.22140538]
 [ 1.45099729  4.78483091]
 [ 2.64634224  7.34825644]
 [ 3.24401472  8.62996921]]
```

Comment: yes!, thank you is what I wanted to do but did not know how